# Create a Python program to modify the text files of a directory whose name end with a digit

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm looking for help. Below is a program I have recently created.

```
def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):
ifile_name = open(ifile_name, 'r')
lines = ifile_name.readlines()

ofile_name = open(ofile_name, "w")

start = 0
end = len(lines) - 1
while start < end:
    ofile_name.write(lines[start])
    ofile_name.write(lines[end])
    start += 1
    end -= 1
if start == end:
    ofile_name.write(lines[start])
ifile_name.close()
ofile_name.close()
```

When the code executes it changes the format of the input file and then outputs this to an output file.

I now want to bring this code further. I want to create a program that will run this program but only make changes to a file which ends with a digit. For example, I have a folder of files in this order

```
file_1
file_a
file_b
file_2
file_3
```

I want to be able to create a program, or if it can be done, to modify my current program to only make changes to a file in a specified directory ending with a digit. Just wondering if anyone has any advice or help as to how I could go about this?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I have created some code which looks like the following. It runs with no errors, however it does not make any changes the file.

```
def my_main():
for filenames in os.listdir("D:/College 3rd year/Semester 1/Scripting/Assignment2/ex09/"):
    if filenames.endswith("1"):
        execfile('C:/Users/Colin/Desktop/Python/ex01.py')
```

In the "ex09" directory there is a file called "file_1", is my code sufficient to make changes to file_1 by executing my previous python program?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question.

Comment: Look into [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: Hi @shuttle87 , I have looked into os. I have updated some code into my question.

Comment: The indentation is still broken.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you will need to use regex for your code to know that each file will be called with a `file_(x)` pattern.  where **x** is the number of the file. Therefore, your code will identify your file name by the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of all files ending in a digit using glob:

```
import glob
flist = glob.glob('*[0-9]')
```